# How to have local alignment groups within the same 'align' environment?

Tags: math-mode, align

For the following, I need to find a cleaner way of having one `alignat` environment and aligning the first two lines with each other while aligning the last two lines with each other so that the vertical spacing is consistent across all the lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{fleqn}[0pt]
        \begin{alignat}{2}
            & a &&= b\\
            %
            & x &&= y
        \end{alignat}\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}
        \begin{alignat}{2}
            & a &&= b\\
            %
            & xxx &&= yyy
        \end{alignat}
    \end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you interested in the equation numbering at all?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I am

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `\belowdisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayskip`, but also take care that the interline spacing in displays is enlarged by `\jot`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[14em]
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & a &&= b\\
  & x &&= y
\end{alignat}\par\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\dimeval{-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip+\jot}}\noindent
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & a &&= b\\
  & xxx &&= yyy
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note.** I used `twocolumn` and 14em just in order to move the equations nearer to the numbers and better show the alignment in a smaller picture.

Answer (score 2):

This solution (which is inspired by code from appendix D of The TeXbook) follows each `alignat` group with a statement that works its way recursively up the vertical list and re-inserts only the `\hbox`es and `\penalty`s produced by the alignment while removing vertical space from the bottom and top.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\def\unpack{\unskip\unpenalty\unskip % remove space from bottom
  \count0=\lastpenalty\unpenalty
  \setbox0=\lastbox
  \ifhbox0{\unpack}\box0 \penalty\count0 \else
  \unskip\unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unskip\unskip % remove space from top
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}[0pt]
\vbox{
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & a &&= b\\
  & x &&= y
\end{alignat}
\par\unpack
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & a &&= b\\
  & xxx &&= yyy
\end{alignat}
\par\unpack
}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `\vbox` is necessary because `\lastbox` cannot be used on the main vertical list.

Comment: See my edited answer.